# How to get the java.lang.reflect.Type of an instantiated generic type?

Tags: java

I understand that it's not possible to do something like `SomeClass<T>.class` at compile time, since it's not instantiated. However, is there a way to express something like `List<SomeClass>.class`? The compiler wouldn't let me. But this information should be available at compile time. I could do `List.class` but it's too generic.

Context: I'm using Gson to serialize a class and I need to do some customization for a field which happens to be a generic type `List<T>`. Gson allows me to register an adapter for a certain type:

```
public GsonBuilder registerTypeAdapter(Type type, Object typeAdapter)
```

My `List<T>` can only be instantiated with two concrete type parameters, so I'm planning on writing two type adapters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***No***, doing anything like `Class<GenericType>.class` is impossible.

Code like this `Class<GenericType>.class` has to be run either in the method/constructor or in the init/static init block. The problem is that the bytecode itself has (*almost*) no knowledge about generic types of the original object, so smth like:

```
public Class<?> getFieldClass() {
    return List<SomeClass>.class;
}
```

Does not work, since there is no information about `List`'s generic type in runtime, so `javac` just does not let you compile that.

[This is done mostly because of the backward compatibility of Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se6/jls3.pdf) (see 4.7 Section). However, there are ***some*** meta-info about generics that is available in runtime. This is not info about the locals as we saw, but this is the info about the generics in the definition of the `Type`'s (class, interface, enum, etc), information about the fields (like your field in object), methods and e.t.c. This information is accessible via reflection descriptors such as `java.lang.reflect.Field`, `java.lang.reflect.Method`, and so on.

**The problem is that this meta-information is static**. For method for instance, it just describes the generic signature, like what is the generic type accepted/returned. You cannot access any actual runtime type by using reflection.

So in your case, I suggest you rethink your class design or rethink the approach. In your current case, you just cannot get the actual generic class in runtime for `List<T>`, you just cannot.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Looks like JVM is quite different from .NET runtime in this regard. I also did some debugging into gson code after posting the question. It doesn't seem to know the instantiated generic at runtime of the field either. It simply treats it as `List<T>`, which matches exactly your explanation. Oh well... I guess I'll just have to write some boilerplate code. Not the end of the world though.

Comment: Yes, JVM is very different from C# in terms of generics. Java and C# took different approaches to implement generics, therefore this difference. In Java you have type erasure therefore `List<String>` is the same as `List` in runtime, but in the C# the generic info is not erased at compile time, so getting the parametrized type class is possible